# Why is jQuery UI Sortable not reordering the elements anymore?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have created a draggable and sortable project. You should be able to drag the drop-down element up top onto the red box. That element will appear in the red box, and some new form elements will appear in the blue box. You should then be able to drag more elements onto the red box, and reorder them. It should act like [this example](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable) from jQuery. I don't actually handle the placement of the objects, I leave that to jQuery.

At the moment I can add new elements to the red box, but the existing elements won't move around to allow me to place the new element where ever in the list. Also when I try to reorganize the existing list, when ever I select an element it will appear in the first position, I can drag it around, the list won't react again, and when I try to place it elsewhere in the list it will just drop in it's original place.

Sortable is set in the html in `<div id="visual_form" class="sortable col-md-6">place data here</div>`, and all of the events set for it in the JS file seem to still fire.

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    over: function() {
      removeIntent = false;
    },
    out: function() {
      removeIntent = true;
    },
    beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
      if (removeIntent === true) {
        var element_id = ui.item[0].id;
        model.remove_element(element_id);
        element_view.remove_element(ui.item);
      }
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      var element = ui.item;
      var new_element = element_view.add_element(element, id);
      if (new_element) {
        var form_element_type = element[0].classList[0];
        var form_data = model.add_element_information_to_model(id, form_element_type);
        data_view.add_element(id, form_data);
        id++;
      }
      var list_of_element_ids = element_view.get_order_of_elements();
      data_view.update_order(list_of_element_ids);
      model.reorder_elements(list_of_element_ids);
    }
  });
```

None of these functions actually affect the layout of the elements in the red box. Some affect the blue box, but that is a separated reaction to what happens in the red box.

I can't figure out if there it is something about jQuery and Sortable that I messed up, or if it just some code I have written, but I think it might be something wrong with the html itself.
What is canceling out the sortable functionality?

See the code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AZJzHixl0EhzogJw9OKR?p=preview)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/O5Ifvrw.gif

Comment: @j08691 fair point but that's part of the problem, in this case I'm not sure what code is relevant in this case.

Comment: In general you should always post the code in question to the problem. If you're not sure what code to post, then take a few minutes to reduce the code to a bare minimum example.

Comment: @j08691: My coffee is now all over my desk -- but that is a glorious meme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, in the HTML I used bootstrap to set the column size

```
<div class="dropDown form-group draggable">
          <div>
            <label class="col-xs-12">dropdown</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control col-xs-12">
              <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
              <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I have to dig a little deeper to find the reasoning be hind this `col-xs-12` it started working again.

I can add the bootstrap column later on with toggleClass.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you might be using the wrong selector:

Try:

```
$("#form_display").sortable({});
```

Or: Try adding the sortable class to `#form_display`

I did test this and the boxes were sortable. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have questions.